# Change code without relaunching Xcode

Tags: xcode, build, compilation

I've heard that the Xcode has an option to change the code and attach it directly to the existing build (run in the simulator for example).
It would be great if you have to move through many screens in the iOS application to get to the same location as before (menu1 -> menu2 -> menu3 -> content)

1. Could you please give me some info - what is the name of that process?
2. How can I do it?
3. How does it really work? - Let's say I've two UIViewControllers - one is with the table (let's call it MenuVC) - list of objects and once the cell was selected the second UIV.C. (let's call it DetailVC) is displayed showing details of that object. Will I've to go back to the MenuVC, do some magic tricks with Xcode and display the DetailVC again by pressing the cell? Or will the DetailVC be changed by itself but remembering the properties I've passed using MenuVC?

Comment: Basically, you want to be able to change the code without exiting the simulator?

Answer (score 2):

That feature was called "fix and continue", but it fell into disrepair and was removed from Xcode 4.

Comment: Oh that's bad. So I need to continue every time relaunching the code I need to go through many steps, meanwhile waiting for the list from the servers only to check how the view controller looks with a different text color? It doesn't sound like step forward.

Comment: If that's all you need to do, you can just call the method that sets the text color from gdb.